# Leanest android mod?

Tags: custom-roms, rom

What is leanest android mod out there?
I do not particularly like new Android or Cyanogenmod 12. Too much flashy animations and too much bloatware with tasks running in background.

Or if not specific mod, what are ways of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable animations from **Developer Options** and can uninstall bloatware using [System App Uninstaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ljmobile.system.app) or [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro).

The background tasks you mentioned are usually services that can be disabled using [Servicely](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.franco.servicely). I've heard that [Amplify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ryansteckler.nlpunbounce) is also good.

**Note**: All of the aforesaid apps require root access.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one way of achieving this is by installing ROM with pico gapps package. And then install fdroid instead of google play.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall bloteware using root apps
disable animations in developer options
remove colors using themes (cyanogenmod)